Sudoku generator takes way too long to remove the tiles
I am trying to generate a sudoku board base on a difficulty. I'm basing everything on the fact that I dont care if it has one or multiple solutions. Generation a full board is ok, its fast, but when it comes to removing the tiles on ADVANCED difficulty, it becomes a nightmare. It can take up to 30 seconds before it generates something.
def is_valid(array, r, c, e):
    size = 3

    not_in_row = e not in array[r]
    if not not_in_row:
        return False

    not_in_column = e not in [array[i][c] for i in range(len(array))]
    if not not_in_column:
        return False

    not_in_cell = e not in [array[i][j] for i in range(int(r // size * size), int(r // size * size + size)) for j in
                            range(int(c // size * size), int(c // size * size + size))]
    if not not_in_cell:
        return False

    return True


def solve(board, r=0, c=0):
    if c == 9:
        if r == 8:
            return True
        r += 1
        c = 0

    if board[r][c] > 0:
        return Sudoku.solve(board, r, c + 1)

    for k in range(1, 10):

        if Sudoku.is_valid(board, r, c, k):
            board[r][c] = k
            if Sudoku.solve(board, r, c + 1):
                return True

        board[r][c] = 0

    return False


def remove_cells(board, cells, difficulty = Difficulty.EASY):
    n_cells = 81 - {
        Difficulty.ADVANCED: rd.randint(20, 29),
        Difficulty.INTERMEDIATE: rd.randint(30, 39),
        }.get(difficulty, rd.randint(40, 49))

    cpt = 0

    while n_cells != 0:
        i, j = cells[cpt]
        temp = board[i][j]
        board[i][j] = 0
        if Sudoku.solve(board.copy()):
            n_cells -= 1
        else:
            board[i][j] = temp
        cpt += 1


And profiling says you're spending your time where? I would guess in solve, because that's not a very smart solver, plus it's recursive in a language that's not known for fast function calls.

How do you call this function? What is cells?

"Generation a full board is ok": is this full board a valid sudoku or not?

I am afraid helping would be require rewriting whole algorithm. I can only suggest to look up how others create sudoku boards (and solve them), then go from there.

This should be feasible with instantaneous results.  Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581709/5237560

When you create a solved sudoku, and then empty one or more cells, you never have to check if that mutated board is still solvable, because it surely is.
So, you should just start with a solved sudoku and then clear some cells without any check.
Some other remarks:

is_valid code could be optimized a bit, avoiding creating lists, and instead iteration with combrehension (using all or any)
In solve I would also avoid making recursive calls when the current cell has a value: just look for the next empty cell with a loop instead of recursion.
In solve you'll get faster solutions on average if you shuffle the values from 1..9 and try them (as k) in that shuffled order. This has also as nice side-effect that if you run it on an empty board, you get a completely random solved Sudoku.

Here is a complete piece of code that does the job:
import random as rd

def is_valid(array, r, c, value):
    # Some optimizations applied here:
    return (value not in array[r] 
        and all(row[c] != value for i, row in enumerate(array))
        and all(
            value not in array[i] or array[i].index(value) // 3 != c // 3
            for i in range(r - r % 3, r - r % 3 + 3) 
        ))

def solve(board, r=0, c=0):
    while r < 9: # Iterate here instead of making recursive calls
        if board[r][c] == 0:
            break
        c = (c + 1) % 9
        r += not c
    else:
        return True

    values = list(range(1, 10))
    rd.shuffle(values)  # Shuffle to get faster results on average
    for k in values:
        if is_valid(board, r, c, k):
            board[r][c] = k
            if solve(board, r + (c == 8), (c + 1) % 9):
                return True

        board[r][c] = 0

    return False


def remove_cells(board, num_cells_to_remove):
    # Get all possible cell coordinates and shuffle them
    cells = [(i, j) for i in range(9) for j in range(9)]
    # Select the desired number from them
    for i, j in rd.sample(cells, k=num_cells_to_remove):
        # If we started out with a solved board,
        #   it is not needed to see if the sudoku is solvable
        board[i][j] = 0

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(map(str, row)))
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create empty board
    board = [ [0] * 9 for _ in range(9) ]
    # Randomly populate as completed, valid sudoku (solved)
    solve(board)
    print_board(board)
    
    # Remove desired number of cells:
    remove_cells(board, 50)
    print_board(board)```

